# use sass transformer in intellij dart

Tags: intellij-idea, sass, dart

When I use the dart plugin and a "Javascript Debug" Run/Debug Configuration ([idea config site](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-and-debugging-dart.html#d489033e320)) and use the sass transformer ([sass package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sass)) the transformer is not called.

Running `pub serve` executes the transformer correctly.

How do I tell Intellij to use the transformer?

Comment: I have used an absolute path for the css file.  pub serve doesn't have any problems with this, but intellij requires the projectName/web prefix.  (I missed this, because my dartium doesn't display any ui fonts, but that's another problem).

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to do in IntelliJ. Maybe ensure you don't enable the SASS watcher in IntelliJ as well, they might collide.
This might be a bug in the SASS transformer or your pubspec.yaml.

Answer (score 2):

Pub Serve should be started automatically by the IDE when you start your run configuration. Take a look at Pub Serve tool window, may be there are any errors/warnings.